# boosting performance in android

Tags: android

i've done an android app that retrieves data from the interent , format it and display it in a customized rows . However the performance is slow. So , is there any general guidelines or checklist to boost up the performance on android app.

Comment: If the problem is network IO, you could try pre-fetching and caching data before it is required so that it can be displayed immediately when the user requests it.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine precisely where your problem lies.

Comment: You can ignore my problem and answer in general .. i'm asking for a guidelines to follow in the future .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a read through the android developer documents. There are lots of handy tips and tricks for optimizing your app.

There is a general guide about boosting performance [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/performance.html)

Seeing as you are retrieving data from the internet, it is important to run background threads to retrieve data. This will stop your interface from "hanging" and becoming unresponsive while the data is being received. Two useful articles [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html)

It also may be a good idea to take steps to optimize your user interface a bit. article [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html)